# Add Item into a generic List in C#

Tags: c#

I tried to insert an object into a generic BindingList. 
But if I try to add a specific object the compiler says: 
*"Argument type ... is not assignable to parameter type"*

```
private void JoinLeaveItem<T>(BindingList<T> collection)
    {

        if (collection.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0] == typeof(UserInformation))
        {
            var tmp = new UserInformation();
            collection.Add(tmp);
        }
    }
```

Please help me

Comment: Why use a generic collation if you are using a specific type `UserInformation`?

Comment: Because this code is not complete ... I would like to add sometihing like

Comment: var tmp2 = new GroupInformation()

Comment: OK. How are `GroupInformation` and `UserInformation` related to each other? Is there an inheritance hierarchy between them and any other type you want to add to the collection?

Comment: No hierarchy and yes I would like to be able to but any Object into this collection...

Comment: You can use `List<Object>` or `ArrayList` for this, but then you loose all the benefits of generics. It is a code smell that you need such a list of _unrelated types_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have objects of two different types that does not have a common anscestor in a strongly typed list. That is: In your case you will need to different collections unless your two (or more) classes have a common base class.

Try creating overloads instead, like this

```
private void JoinLeaveItem(BindingList<UserInformation> collection)
{
    collection.Add(new UserInformation());
}

private void JoinLeaveItem(BindingList<GroupInformation> collection)
{
    collection.Add(new GroupInformation());
}
```

Use it like this

```
JoinLeaveItem(userInformationCollection)
JoinLeaveItem(groupInformationCollection)
```

Note: I've inlined the `tmp` variable.

Comment: The idea is that I can but BindingList as UserInformation or GroupInformation as well!

Comment: @user1374495 nice. glad to help. :) If you find the answer helpful, please mark it as accepted by clicking the green checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've described in your comments do you want to do something like this....

```
private void JoinLeaveItem<T>(BindingList<T> collection)  where T: new()
    { 
            var tmp = new T(); 
            collection.Add(tmp); 
    }
```

EDIT
If you want to add extra Tests to limit to only the items you specify you could add a big test at the beginning

```
private void JoinLeaveItem<T>(BindingList<T> collection)  where T: new()
    { 
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(UserInformation) || typeof(T) == typeof(GroupInformation) 
            var tmp = new T(); 
            collection.Add(tmp); 
        } 
    }
```

Alternatively you can make a more generic solution via use of an interface.

Define an interface

```
public interface ILeaveItem { }
```

Make UserInformation and GroupInformation inherit from it and then use

```
private void JoinLeaveItem<T>(BindingList<T> collection)  where T: ILeaveItem, new()
    { 
            var tmp = new T(); 
            collection.Add(tmp); 
    }
```

Comment: Yes but how I can put now specific Objects like UserInformation and or GroupInformations ?

Comment: @user1374495 What do you mean? with this code if BindingList is a collection of UserInformation it will determine the type of T and insert a UserInformation object, if BindingList is a collection of GroupInformation it will insert a GroupInformation object

Comment: @user1374495, from your comments on the question you've said that you want either GroupInformation or UserInformation to appear in the same collection at the same time?